# jQuery UI datepicker on mobile Safari (iPhone) month/year dropdown strange behaviour

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile-safari, jquery-ui-datepicker

**This issue is apparent on mobile Safari on an iPhone** (I haven't tested on other iOS devices) but I have not been able to reproduce on Windows or Android.

A simple version can be found at https://jsfiddle.net/DaveParsons/havwgb2u/

I'm unable to use the native `<input type="date">` as I require the flexibility of the datepicker.

To reproduce simply select a different month from the datepicker control then click on a day in the calendar or the random element - the iOS picker wheel re-appears.

Is there some way of letting iOS know it doesn't need to keep popping the picker up.

```js
$("#date").datepicker({
  changeYear: true,
  changeMonth: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<form>

  <div id="date">
  </div>

  <button type="submit">
    Test
  </button>

  <div>
    <p>
      random element <a href="#">with link</a>
    </p>
  </div>

</form>
```